# Is it possible to concatenate data from a row and a column together to display on the axis of a line graph?

Tags: excel, concatenation, linegraph

In Excel, if I have data entered in a matrix format with rows representing years and the columns representing quarters, is there a method to concatenate the row/column names together when selecting the axis label range of a line graph?

[Data Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZxk7.jpg)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHg3t.jpg)

[Select Axis Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBnzg.jpg)

In regards to the image of the graph, I have just selected the cells containing Qtr 1, Qtr 2, Qtr 3, Qtr 4 over and over again to get the output.

The simple solution would be to just create a new column containing the desired data. However, the spreadsheet I'm working on has dozens of similar data entry points, which is why I'm looking to see if there is another solution.

Note: I don't seem to have enough reputation to embed images yet, so I can only link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image below, I've shown part of your data table and a rearranged version of it.  With the rearranged table, the graph is made naturally using a scatter plot, at the right.
[image]
Notice that each quarter is shown by the minor gridlines. This may not be what you want, but it fits very well with how Excel does things.

Here's some code to convert your type of data table to the rearranged version. To run it, first select the data portion of your data table and then run the code. Let me know if you have questions.

```
Sub qtrTable()
Dim r As Range, qtr As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
Set qtr = Selection
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select new table location", "Upper left", qtr(1, 1).Offset(0, 6).Address, , , , , Type:=8)
For i = 1 To qtr.Rows.Count
  For j = 0 To 3
    r.Offset(j, 0) = qtr(i, 1) + j * 0.25
    r.Offset(j, 1) = qtr(i, j + 2)
  Next j
  Set r = r.Offset(4, 0)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Didn't quite answer my question but it has given me something to think about.

Comment: I’m glad you got some insight. I suppose I should have been more explicit and stated that I don’t believe there is a simple answer to your question. So I was trying to encourage you to rearrange how you think about it so that you could obtain the Excel graph as simply as possible

Comment: I'm gonna give you the answer anyway because this helped quite a bit. Thanks mate.

Comment: I'm very glad you were helped.   I admit that there are ways to do your problem other than what I've shown -- but they're unnecessarily complicated.  Over the years I've learned to rearrange my way of thinking about problems to fit in with how Excel does things, and as a result I've become amazed at how much can be done.